# Cannot click/select password fields in firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, select, passwords, click

I am not able to click on password field  and its weird but finally got solution so sharing it with everyone on stack overflow as I was not able not find it here.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  For general issues, you should post this to https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Language Support -> Keyboard input method system and select XIM instead of IBus. Restart/logout.

Find more details here

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1214123?page=2